# neo4j shortest path with label constraint

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

looking to understand if anything can be done to make the query below performant on a large graph.  I'm trying to find the shortest path between two nodes but exclude paths that include certain other kinds of nodes. The issue seems to be the WHERE clause. The query below just completely grinds to a halt.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((p1:Party{suprRC:"21"})-[*..15]-(p2:Party{suprRC:"21"}))
WITH p
WHERE NONE(n in nodes(p) where labels(n) in [["Reporter"],["FirstName"],["LastName"]]) 
RETURN p limit 500;
```

Comment: You might try the WHERE directly on the MATCH (leave the WITH p out in other words).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tom - I'm afraid it didn't help though.

Comment: Couple of questions ... 1) the starting node and the end node are ... the same ? Is suprRC a unique property for a Party ? If not, are the Party nodes indexed on suprRC (I know that should be obvious, I'm just excluding options here) ? When you execute just the MATCH (with the RETURN and LIMIT but without WITH and WHERE) ... is that performant ? Can you share the output of a EXPLAIN of this query ?

Comment: Hi Tom - 1) The starting node and end node are not the same. suprRC is not unique for a party. I have not indexed the party nodes yet - I know I should, but since the query dies when I add the piece filtering the paths for node labels I felt reasonably confident that this wasn't the issue. When I omit the WHERE and WITH pieces it is very performant. In fact, the last two node exclusions, in particular 'FirstName', are what kill the performance.

Comment: Looks like I can't add an image to SO quite yet. It's short enough, here's my ascii version of it:

Comment: Looks like I can't add an image to SO quite yet. It's short enough, here's my text version. 1) Start with two NodeByLabelScan with 16,499 estimated rows each. 2) Filter each of those results to obtain 1,650 estimated rows each. 3) Form CartesianProduct (2,722,170 rows). 4) Calculated ShortestPath (2,722,170 estimated rows), 5) Projection (2,722,170 rows). 6) Filter (2,041,628 estimated rows 7) Limit,8) Produce Results,9) Result.

Comment: Adding an index on supRC will improve things a bit ... but as you say it's not the determining factor. Would it be possible/permitted to get the actual dataset (or even better zip of the database) ?

Comment: Hi Tom - I'm planning on putting a version of the dataset out there, but it may take some time. In the meantime, I did get some help from the Neo4J folks and one interesting suggestion was to reformulate the match so that instead of the WHERE clause, I'm specifying the allowed links in the relationship piece of the match as follows: [:RELTYPE1|:RELTYPE2|...|:RELTYPEN]. I this way, all I have to know is which 'next hops' are allowed from each node.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is wrong, `labels(n)` returns a collection of labels and you will match a collection against a collection of single String elements.

As mentioned by Tom, you can leave off the WITH but you will have to use two `NONE` predicates

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((p1:Party{suprRC:"21"})-[*..15]-(p2:Party{suprRC:"21"}))
WHERE NONE(x IN nodes(p) 
             WHERE NONE(l IN ['Reporter','LastName', 'FirstName'] 
                      WHERE l IN labels(x)
                      )
          )
RETURN p limit 500;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Christophe. I don't recall why I used the particular idiom I did - though it does work (with smaller graphs/queries anyway). I tried the one you suggested and it also worked, but is still too slow (30 minutes for query to finish). Ugh.